# Drupal 7 expanding fields

Tags: drupal-7, relationship, field, taxonomy

I have a field in a cms called 'services' the services is a lsit of checkboxes with the values

```
1|digital
2|web
3|print
4|apps
```

The issue is each of the options has a related url. Is there way to link a url to a 'service' or am I looking at taxonomy to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a taxonomy. A select list is simply a key/value pair with no other additional data. If you build a new taxonomy, you can either use the taxonomy URL for your purpose or you can add a Link field and give each term a specific URL and tie that in somehow, maybe through Views or a custom display.